# Gate resistor of an IGBT

Tags: gate-driving, igbt

I have trouble choosing an IGBT gate driver for PMSM motor control application. We are planning to use a custom inverter with a custom PCB that has the FS150R12N2T7_B15 module.  We do not know the right value of the external gate resistor in order for our gate drivers and the actual switch to work properly. Can somebody please help us?

Comment: The assumption is that you are referring to the series ‘gate stopper’ resistor. This resistor is intended to slow the turn on/off of the switching device to eliminate ringing due to stray inductances in the emitter/source path. Usual values are around 10-22Ohms are can be determined empirically (build prototype and adjust the value for best result).